# c99 -- expected expression before return

Tags: c, recursion, c99

The following recursive function should return 0 if the sum of the provided array is negative, and 1 if the sum is greater than or equal to 0. I don't understand why I get an "error: expected expression before `return`" when compiling it.

```
int restituisco(int *p, int len) {

    int somma;

    if (len == 0)
        if (somma < 0)
            return 0;
        else 
            return 1;

    somma = p[len-1] + restituisco(p,--len);
}
```

Comment: You can't use `return` as part of an expression.

Comment: okay i changed the function to "int restituisco(int *p, int len) {

 int somma;
 
 if (len == 0)
  if (somma < 0)
   return 0;
  else 
   return 1;

 somma = p[len-1] + restituisco(p,--len);
}"

Comment: Please edit your question, it's hard to read code in comments.  However, note that you are using `somma` before initializing it, which is bad.

Comment: I edited the code in the post. Why the function returns somma instead of returning 1 or 0 depending on if somma is >=0 or less than 0?

Comment: You need to fix the code so that `somma` has a value when you test it. If we can't tell what you meant, then the compiler certainly can't.